# How can i simulate a pressed button with the enter key in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

my goal is to launch a function in python by simply clicking on the enter key on my keyboard instead of the push button (using Qtdesigner). To put you in context, I have a barcode scanner, this one will read the code and write it in a lineEdit, the scanner is programmed to press enter directly, I would like to take this opportunity to perform my search function instead of clicking the button.
I hope I was clear, you can contact me for more information. Thank you in advance dear community.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15567835/9267296) answer your question?

Comment: Yes it does thank you.